# get a list of all files inside a directory outside the system folder

Tags: php, yii

i am new to yii and i need to get a list of files inside a directory outside of the system folder. i tried it with

```
        $fileListOfDirectory = array();
        $pathTofileListDirectory = Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/path/to/files';
        foreach( new DirectoryIterator($pathTofileListDirectory) as $file) {
            if( $file->isFile() === TRUE && $file->getBasename() !== '.DS_Store' && substr(strrchr($file->getPathname(), '.'), 1) == 'txt') {
                array_push($fileListOfDirectory, $file->getBasename());
            }
        }
```

but I allways get the error

> DirectoryIterator::__construct(/myYiiInstallation/system/path/to/files)
>   [directoryiterator.--construct]:
>   failed to open dir: No such file or directory

from the line

```
foreach( new DirectoryIterator($pathTofileListDirectory) as $file) {
```

So is there another way to get the list of files or what should I do?
thnx!

Comment: hey, the code works - there was an error in the path: I needed to add a '/../' to it. sorry - my bad!

Comment: You should really either delete the question or add the answer yourself and accept it.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should try http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CApplication#basePath-detail instead of using the baseUrl in your file system.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this ....

```
$fileListOfDirectory = array ();
$pathTofileListDirectory = Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/path/to/files' ;

if(!is_dir($pathTofileListDirectory ))
{
    die(" Invalid Directory");
}

if(!is_readable($pathTofileListDirectory ))
{
    die("You don't have permission to read Directory");
}

foreach ( new DirectoryIterator ( $pathTofileListDirectory ) as $file ) {
    if ($file->isFile () === TRUE && $file->getBasename () !== '.DS_Store') {

        if ($file->getExtension () == "txt") {
            array_push ( $fileListOfDirectory, $file->getBasename () );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: of course it does give me the 'txt' string. please try by yourself to proof. but hey - this doesn't throw me the error I need to solve here... ;-)